# Get Top 5 by Different years MDX

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, mdxstudio, mdxclient

I have a top 5 of Customers by year and I want to create a query that gets this information per year in different years at the same time, I mean:

```
select 
[Measures].[Ventas] 
on columns,
non empty
topcount
(
[Dim Cliente].[Company Name].Children,5,[Measures].[Ventas]
) 
on rows
from 
[DWH Northwind]
where 

[Dim Tiempo].[Año].&[1996]
```

TOP 5 1996

[image: TOP 5 1996]

Could I get Top 5 of 1996 and 1997 together separated per year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Generate](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Generate.php) function as following:

```
select 
  [Measures].[Ventas] on columns,

  non empty Generate(
    { [Dim Tiempo].[Año].&[1995], [Dim Tiempo].[Año].&[1996] } as yy,
    topcount (yy.currentMember * [Dim Cliente].[Company Name].Children,5,[Measures].[Ventas]) 
  ) on rows

from [DWH Northwind
```

This way you could retrieve the TOP 5 for each available years the same way:

```
select 
  [Measures].[Ventas] on columns,

  non empty Generate(
    [Dim Tiempo].[Año].members as yy,
    topcount (yy.currentMember * [Dim Cliente].[Company Name].Children,5,[Measures].[Ventas]) 
  ) on rows

from [DWH Northwind
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Salute man, Now that is one clever use of Generate function. Awesome, simply Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select 
[Measures].[Ventas] 
on columns,
non empty
{
topcount
(([Dim Tiempo].[Año].&[1996],[Dim Cliente].[Company Name].Children),5,[Measures].[Ventas]) 
,
topcount
(([Dim Tiempo].[Año].&[1997],[Dim Cliente].[Company Name].Children),5,[Measures].[Ventas]) 
}
on rows
from 
[DWH Northwind]
where
```